# R Shiny: include image in modalDialog

Tags: r, shiny

I want to show an image in a modalDialog, but R does not render one.

The following code only shows a link to the Google logo, but not the Google logo itself:

Server.R:

```
observeEvent(input$button, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Title",
      '<img>https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png</img>',
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
```

UI.R

```
actionButton(inputId ="button", label = "Click me")
```

Comment: Try enclosing it in `HTML(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        showModal(modalDialog(
          title = "Title",
          HTML('<img src="http://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">'),
          easyClose = TRUE,
          footer = NULL
        ))

  })
```

There is an error in your html. Use the `HTML(...)` tag to specify html code and then specify the source in the `<img>` tag. The above code works for me.

Comment: What if I want to add same image into title? I am getting a broken image if I add same code in title.